# Rings of Akhaten: Clara as a Companion

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

During the [*Rings of Akhaten*](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rings_of_Akhaten_(TV_story)), the Doctor mentions that he had been here before with his granddaughter, Susan. I know she was left on Earth to teach. Knowing that Clara teaches English and her mention of Marcus Aurelius in the [*Day of the Doctor*](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)) (a reference to previous travel by the first Doctor). Is Matt Smith's Doctor or the writer(s) choosing Clara as a companion as a reminder of his granddaughter, or is it the writer's choice to be an aesthetically beautiful thing?

Comment: as far as we know, the writers have largely forgotten Susan existed beyond that one throw-away line Moffet tossed in as an Easter Egg.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the premise of your question is wrong, there was never any mention on the show that Susan had been left on Earth to "teach" (maybe you are thinking of Ian and Barbara, the two human companions who traveled with the Doctor and Susan at the start of the show, and who were both Susan's teachers when Susan was a student at the [Coal Hill School](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Coal_Hill_School), the same school that Clara would later teach at). If you look at the end of the transcript of *The Dalek Invasion of Earth* [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/2-2.htm), the reason she's left behind is that she's fallen in love with a resistance fighter named David, and now that the Dalek invasion has been repelled, the Doctor thinks she'll be better off settling down with him on a single planet rather than continuing to travel around the universe with himself and his other two companions Ian and Barbara.

From the transcript, here's the ending scene from that episode where Susan is left behind:

> DAVID: Susan?
>
> SUSAN: Yes, David?
>
> DAVID: Please stay. Please stay here with me.
>
> SUSAN: I can’t stay, David. I don’t belong to this time.
>
> DAVID: But I love you, Susan, and I want you to marry me.
>
> SUSAN: You see, David. Grandfather’s old now. He needs me. Oh, don’t
>   make me choose between you and him, please!
>
> DAVID: But you told me! You said that you’d never known the security
>   of living in one place and one time. Look, you said it was something
>   that you always longed for. Well, I’m giving you that, Susan. I’m
>   giving you a place, a time, an identity.
>
> SUSAN: No, David! (crying) I’ve lost my shoe. Oh David, I do love you!
>   I do, I do, I do!  (Inside the Tardis, the Doctor closes the doors)
>
> SUSAN: Grandfather!
>
> DOCTOR [OC]: Listen, Susan, please. I’ve double-locked the doors. You
>   can’t get in. Now move back, child, where I can see you.
>
> DOCTOR: During all the years, I’ve been taking care of you, you in
>   return have been taking care of me.
>
> SUSAN [on scanner]: Oh, Grandfather, I belong with you!
>
> DOCTOR: Not any longer, Susan. You’re still my grandchild and always
>   will be, but now, you’re a woman too.
>
> DOCTOR [OC]: I want you to belong somewhere, to have roots of your
>   own. With David, you’ll be able to find those roots and live normally
>   like any woman should do.
>
> DOCTOR: Believe me, my dear, your future lies with David, and not with
>   a silly old buffer like me. One day, I shall come back. Yes, I shall
>   come back. Until then, there must be no regrets, no tears, no
>   anxieties. Just go forward in all your beliefs, and prove to me that I
>   am not mistaken in mine. Goodbye, Susan, goodbye, my dear.
>
> (The Tardis dematerialises. Susan, with only one shoe, walks where it
>   had stood)
>
> DAVID: Susan? Susan? He knew. He knew you could never leave him.
>
> (Susan looks at her Tardis key, then drops it on the ground, and they
>   slowly walk off hand in hand)

The word "teach" and "teacher" don't appear anywhere in the transcript, nor to they appear in her one remaining TV appearance in *The Five Doctors* (transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/20-7.htm)). As for non-TV fiction, that's usually covered by the TARDIS wiki, and the ["adult life" section of Susan's wiki page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Susan_Foreman#Adult_life) doesn't mention any fiction in which she became a teacher.

So since your premise is wrong, I think we can safely say that no, it was not the writer's intention that Matt Smith's Doctor chose Clara as a companion because she reminded him of his granddaughter. In fact the reason he initially wanted her as a companion was pretty clear--she was the "impossible girl" because she appeared to be an exact duplicate of a girl he had met in Victorian London, [Clara Oswin Oswald](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Clara_Oswin_Oswald#Clara_Oswin_Oswald).

Comment: And because she's very pretty.

Comment: But her funny nose...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That cleared everything!

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to assume that there was any deliberate aim to deceive the viewer, nor that the reference to his grand-daughter (presumably Susan) was anything other than a great big nod to what is laughably referred to as the [canon continuity](http://web.archive.org/web/20100708170259/http://www.paulcornell.com/2007/02/canonicity-in-doctor-who.html) between Old Who and New Who.

As to why he chose ***Clara*** as a companion, the answer is that he was...

- Predestined to do so given that she's all over his timeline due to her actions in "[The Name of the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story))"

and

- Frankly he has a 'type' (young, intelligent, exceptionally pretty woman for the most part), as seen in the "[Clara and the TARDIS](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Clara_and_the_TARDIS_%28TV_story%29)" webisode.

Comment: For the record, I'd definitely choose her to come and live in my flying telephone box.

Comment: Can I have a TARDIS? At least tell me where you got it.

Comment: Actually Clara was driven to the Doctor by Missy (aka the Master) who gives her the number of the TARDIS to call. So I would not say she was predestined or something.